# Dell XPS 12 built-in camera not working in skype and cheese

Tags: dell, skype, webcam, camera

So the integrated camera on my XPS 12 doesn't work with Skype. However, when running `$ vlc v4l2:///dev/video0` I do see the video output displayed correctly. Skype is set to use `/dev/video0` In cheese I get about a half second of corrupted video output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find a workaround here: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=192952

The solution uses gstreamer to read from camera and forward the stream to a virtual device.